# How to identify last layers of a model to do transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, ocr, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

first of all: I'm new to Deep Learning and Tensorflow, so sorry for the stupid questions. Maybe someone can help me to gain more understanding and clarity.
I work on an OCR project, where I only have 4000 labeled images with a dotted font and a white background.
I decided to use this code to solve the task: https://github.com/Pay20Y/FOTS_TF

I used the pre-trained model on Synthtext dataset and continued training with my own dataset, but the results were not that good.
I think one problem may be that the number of classes of my custom dataset is less than the number of classes of the pre-trained model.
I read about transfer learning, where you only train the last layers and then you can use a different number of classes, but I don't know how to do this. So to be more precise I don't know how to identify the last layers of the graph?

Here is the code of building the graph:

```
    def cnn(self, rois):
        with tf.variable_scope("recog/cnn"):
            conv1 = slim.conv2d(rois, 64, 3, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=None)
            conv1 = slim.conv2d(conv1, 64, 3, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=None)
            pool1 = slim.max_pool2d(conv1, [2, 1], stride=[2, 1])
            conv2 = slim.conv2d(pool1, 128, 3, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=None)
            conv2 = slim.conv2d(conv2, 128, 3, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=None)
            pool2 = slim.max_pool2d(conv2, [2, 1], stride=[2, 1])
            conv3 = slim.conv2d(pool2, 256, 3, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=None)
            conv3 = slim.conv2d(conv3, 256, 3, stride=1, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=None)
            pool3 = slim.max_pool2d(conv3, [2, 1], stride=[2, 1])
            return pool3
    

    def bilstm(self, input_feature, seq_len):
        with tf.variable_scope("recog/rnn"):
            lstm_fw_cell = rnn.LSTMCell(self.rnn_hidden_num)
            lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_fw_cell, input_keep_prob=self.keepProb, output_keep_prob=self.keepProb)
            lstm_bw_cell = rnn.LSTMCell(self.rnn_hidden_num)
            lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_bw_cell, input_keep_prob=self.keepProb, output_keep_prob=self.keepProb)
            # infer_output, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, input_feature, seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)
            # infer_output, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, input_feature, sequence_length=seq_len, time_major=True, dtype=tf.float32)
            infer_output, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, input_feature, sequence_length=seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)
            # stack_lstm_layer, _, _ = rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, input_feature, dtype=tf.float32)
            infer_output = tf.concat(infer_output, axis=-1)
            return infer_output
            # return stack_lstm_layer

    def build_graph(self, rois, seq_len):
        num_rois = tf.shape(rois)[0]

        cnn_feature = self.cnn(rois) # N * 1 * W * C
        print cnn_feature

        cnn_feature = tf.reshape(cnn_feature, [nums, -1, 256]) # squeeze B x W x C
        cnn_feature = tf.squeeze(cnn_feature, axis=1) # N * W * C
        reshape_cnn_feature = tf.transpose(cnn_feature, (1, 0, 2))
        reshape_cnn_feature = cnn_feature

        # print "final cnn: ", reshape_cnn_feature.shape

        lstm_output = self.bilstm(reshape_cnn_feature, seq_len) # N * T * 2H

        # print "lstm_output: ", lstm_output

        logits = tf.reshape(lstm_output, [-1, self.rnn_hidden_num * 2]) # (N * T) * 2H
        
        W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.rnn_hidden_num * 2, self.num_classes], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0., shape=[self.num_classes]), name="b")

        logits = tf.matmul(logits, W) + b # (N * T) * Class

        logits = tf.reshape(logits, [num_rois, -1, self.num_classes])
        logits = tf.reshape(logits, [nums, -1, self.num_classes])
        logits = tf.reshape(logits, [num_rois, -1, self.num_classes])
        
        logits = tf.transpose(logits, (1, 0, 2))

        return logits
```

I don't know if it is smart to do transfer learning?
Is there still another way to use the pre-trained model and finetune on my own dataset, but with another number of character classes?
I'm really confused how to solve this task and what to try to improve the results. I already tried training from scratch without a pre-trained model, but than the model overfitts.

Comment: have you tried different models for your OCR problem?

Comment: what do you mean with different models? Do you mean different pre-trained models?

Comment: As you said you didn't get a better score by using this model, so why not use the SOTA model (i.e. ABCNet). FYI, for the OCR problem, you don't need to train the last layer or something (unlike computer vision problem in general); just initialize with the pre-trained weights and run with few epochs.  AFAIK, you can't re-train the last layer of the OCR model only.

Comment: The last layer of any OCR model is basically the recognition branch to recognize the text. It's combined with the detection branch. To fine-tune on the specific type of text, you need to train on the synth-text data set and fine-tune target specific data set.

Comment: Now as the chosen model already trained on synth-text and fine-tune on benchmark data set (i.e. total-text, icdar, etc), what we can do is take their pre-trained weight and initialize with it to our task or our specific data set.

Comment: Additionally, if our goal text is too different, then the best approach can be to create such type of synth-text data set first (which should be huge enough), and train on it first and fine-tune likewise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailled answer! So can you use ABC net for any kind of text? In my case I dont want to recognize words, but product codes.

Comment: So I already used the model pre-trained on Synthext dataset and finetuned it in my own dataset. But the problem is that it predicts characters that are not even in the character set of my task, but in the character set of the Synthext dataset. Ist there any way to limit the number of characters when finetuning?

Comment: Generally, there is no limit to the number of characters when fine-tuning. However, try MaskTextSpotterV3( https://github.com/MhLiao/MaskTextSpotterV3 ), inference with the pre-trained weights, and see if it's showing any promising results.